A necessary condition on an uncountable subset of $[0, 1]$
I’m trying to prove the following:

If $A \subseteq [0, 1]$ and is uncountable, then there is at least one pair of members of A, call them $x, y$, such that $|x-y|$ is irrational.

I came up with the following, which relies on an existential instantiation argument and subsequently dividing the set A based on that to elements which are greater and smaller, and enumerating them in a way which perhaps presumes the conclusion? I feel a little uneasy about that in particular. is it a legitimate line of reasoning?
———
Proof:
Assume that there is no such pair of members; e.g. the distances between all pairs of members of A are rational.
Let $x_0$ be some member of A (existential instantiation). We’ll denote the members of A smaller than $x_0$ by $x_{-i}, i \in J$ and similarly the members which are larger by $x_i, i \in I$, for some index sets I, J.
Focusing on the members larger than $x_0$ now, we can now define mapping between these $x_i \in A$ and $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$:
$$ 
x_0 \to (0, 0). \\
x_i \to (p_i, q_i) \\
$$
Where $|x_i - x_0| = p_i/q_i$, which we can do based on the assumption all such distances are rational. Moreover, these are all distinct since, when looking only at elements larger than $x_0$ of course distinct elements are at distinct distances.
Therefore we found a one-to-one mapping from $x_i (i \in I)$ to a subset of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ which is countable and so $(x_i)_{i \in I}$ is countable as well.
Using similar reasoning we show the set of elements smaller than $x_0$ is countable, and therefore the union is countable as a countable (finite) union of countable sets, QED.

By denoting, the set of members of $A$ larger than $x_0$ by ${x_i | i =1,2,3,\ldots}$ you implicitly assumed this set to be countable!

Aha, I thought its a bit iffy thank you for pointing that out.. is there a way to salvage this direction at all or I’m off entirely? E.g. I could still try and index the set of larger members by their distance which is rational hence countable no?

I don't know why you got a downvote. I'm not sure now if I should answer it. But I'm giving you hints here in comments. First observe that $A$ must contain uncountably many irrationals. As you started, assume that the distances between all pairs of members of $A$ are rational. Then fix $y \in A$. Then conclude that $x=y + \alpha(x)$ for every $x \in A$, where $\alpha(x)$ is always rational. But ${y + \alpha(x) | \alpha(x) \in \mathbb{Q}}$ is countable! I hope you get what $\alpha$ is.

Thank you Aman! Seems similar to my argument but a bit more careful with the use of indexing over other members, makes sense. Cheers!

This question is similar to: If $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ has positive Lebesgue measure, then there are $x, y \in E$ such that $|x - y|$ is irrational. See this comment.
